# How to fully view cross-signed certificate signatures

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, x.509

Long story short: Security scan raised a flag about a cert, found that it was an expired root on a cross-signed cert. Yadda yadda, updated intermediates, fixed issue.

However, I noticed that `openssl x509 -noout -text intermediate.crt` only lists a single signature on the certificate, even though there are two. I've looked over the man page and I can't find an option that prints additional signatures, and google searches are even *less* useful.

Is there a parser out there somewhere that will list *all* of the signatures on a certificate? I notice that Qualys enumerates and follows the various cert paths, but I'd prefer not to have to make prod changes to view certificate metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There IS only one signature on an X.509 certificate.

But there can be multiple different certificates for a given CA, and multiple different verification paths using DIFFERENT certificates, with one signature on each certificate. That's what Qualys/ssllabs shows you (when detected).

Usually the CA involved will document this; one of my favorites for clarity is [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/). And if your recently-expired bridge was [Sectigo-usertrust-under-addtrust](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020), about which maybe a dozen Qs have already been posted, their picture is less clear but their text is good enough (IMO).

Alternatively, now that [Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency) has become common (though not universal) you can usually (though not always) search on one of the logviewers. I find crt.sh most convenient, e.g. https://crt.sh/?q=usertrust%20rsa%20certification%20authority quickly shows the now-expired bridge, the better root, and the new 'alternate' bridge to AAA, as well as the irrelevant Microsoft codesigning endorsement, all with links for details and download if desired.